# How do I configure a nx build to generate a stacktrace?

Tags: stack-trace, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am using the Nrwl nx console in Visual Studio Code. When I use the build command in the nx console I get the following error.
Building Angular Package

> NX   Entry point "name-of-the-library" has a circular dependency on itself.

Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

I cannot locate any way to "pass" --verbose so I can see the stack trace.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Thank you, Al

Comment: just copy the command the console generates, put it in a terminal and add --verbose

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That works but I'm curious. Is there no way to set --verbose in a configuration since the solution requires leaving VS Code and opening a console. (Not a huge problem but it seems there ought to be a way "configure" nx!)

Comment: The code is open source. Feel free to add, it would be useful